# filename error in online version of excel 365

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet I have been working on in Excel 365 (Version 2209 Build 15629.20208) and I have just uploaded this in to a sharepoint space so others can now use it. When I come to open the spreadsheet there is an error with the following formula that grabs a sheet name -

`=MID(CELL("filename",K1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",K1))+1,255)`

The error is : a value used in this formula is of the wrong data type.

The build of excel in sharepoint shows as 16.0.15825.42300.

Any ideas why this error is happening?

Comment: You can't use `CELL("filename"` in online versions of Excel. It just doesn't work.

Comment: Is there a different way to get the sheet name?

Comment: Click on the link **[CELL()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/cell-function-51bd39a5-f338-4dbe-a33f-955d67c2b2cf)** read the info_type values where filename shows it states that `"filename"

Filename (including full path) of the file that contains reference, as text. Returns empty text ("") if the worksheet that contains reference has not yet been saved.

Note: This value is not supported in Excel for the web, Excel Mobile, and Excel Starter.`

Comment: @Rory wow.... every day learning new things. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @AutomationMonkey you might be able to do something with office scripts, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

CELL() is not supported on the online version but you may use VBA.

- Open VBA Click on ThisWorkBook -> Insert -> Module, copy the below code and save.

---

```
Function TabName()

    TabName = ActiveSheet.Name

End Function

Function GetBook() As String

  GetBook = ActiveWorkbook.Name

End Function
```

Close the VBA window and return to the workbook.

Select a blank cell, type =GetBook() to get the WorkSheet Name or =TabName() to get the WorkBook Tab name..

note: The Excel file must be saved as "Excel Macro-Enable"